# Convert.FromBase64String FormatException

Tags: c#-4.0, cryptography

I get a FormatException for this Convert.FromBase64String method. I don't mind about hardcoding the value. Anyone can explain why I get this exception.

```
        // Instantiate a new RijndaelManaged object to perform string symmetric encryption
        RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

        // Set key and IV
        rijndaelCipher.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("TASK");
        rijndaelCipher.IV = Convert.FromBase64String("0123");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what Base64 is, and what Rijndael keys & IVs are?

Comment: No I don't i just need some quick job to happen :)

Comment: _Do not use cryptography if you don't understand it_.  Otherwise, you **will** create security holes.

Comment: I don't really care about something serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strings aren't valid Base64.

You need to generate two cryptographically secure 256-bit random numbers, convert them to Base64, and embed them in your source.

For example:

```
var alg = new RijndaelManaged();
alg.BlockSize = alg.KeySize = 256;
Console.WriteLine("Key: " + Convert.ToBase64String(alg.Key));
Console.WriteLine("IV:  " + Convert.ToBase64String(alg.IV));
```

Comment: But aren't these random, I would need the crypto key to decrypt it later?  You dont set the Key an IV somewhere!

Comment: You can run this code to generate a random key and IV, then embed the results in your source.